# Decompiling vb.net application

Tags: c#, vb.net, reflector, ilspy, dnspy

```
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    [AccessedThroughProperty("SimpleButton1")]
    private SimpleButton _SimpleButton1;
internal virtual SimpleButton SimpleButton1
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return this._SimpleButton1;
        }
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        [CompilerGenerated]
        set
        {
            EventHandler value2;
            value2 = SimpleButton1_Click;
            SimpleButton simpleButton;
            simpleButton = this._SimpleButton1;
            if (simpleButton != null)
            {
                simpleButton.Click -= value2;
            }
            this._SimpleButton1 = value;
            simpleButton = this._SimpleButton1;
            if (simpleButton != null)
            {
                simpleButton.Click += value2;
            }
        }
    }
```

When i decompile an vb.net application using ilspy, dnspy, just decompile, reflector, etc.

all the decompilers decompiles events in this format. so i cannot open the designer file. is there any other way to decompile properly?
[image]

Comment: The result is autogenerated C# code. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: is there any way to change the code like this? SimpleButton SimpleButton1; and bind the event handling in initializecomponent method. so designer will open

Comment: Not sure really what context you're working here (if this was your app or someone else's, in which case I hope you've got permission)  DevExpress is a 3rd party control suite, have you got the DevExpress.Editors library installed?

Comment: yes. i have installed devexpress.editors installed. this is one of our very old projects. we lost the source code. so we r trying to get the source code from assembly. when i change this code like SimpleButton SimpleButton1;  the designer works. we cannot amend the code like this manually since it is a larger project. so im looking for a way to change the code in this way automatically.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the code that the VB compiler generates for the `Sub X() Handles Field.Event` syntax.
The VB forms designer supports the `Handles` syntax, but the C# forms designer does not have any direct equivalent.
In C#, event handlers are typically registered directly in the `InitializeComponent` method, and do not automatically de/re-register when writing to the field.

To get the designer working, you would need to:

- verify that the property is only set inside `InitializeComponent`, not somewhere else
- move the `SimpleButton.Click += SimpleButton1_Click;` into the `InitializeComponent`, e.g. so that it directly follows the `SimpleButton = new Button()` property assignment.
- if the designer is picky, you may need to explicitly new the eventhandler type with a fully-qualified type name: `SimpleButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(SimpleButton1_Click);`
- delete the property and remove the leading underscore from the field name

I am not aware of any tools that would automate these steps.

Turning off the C# 2.0 feature "Use implicit method group conversions" in the decompiler settings can help with the `new EventHandler` portion.